# AWS EC2 curl request giving host not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I have a curl command which works fine on my local system,
however the same command when run from an EC2 instance gives the error

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: qasu-cmx1.uto-netcom.org

Ive kept HTTP and HTTPS open to the world in the security group of the EC2 instance.

Any thoughts on what could be the possible reason?

Comment: have you tried with another domain, e.g. https://www.google.com?

Comment: `qasu-cmx1.uto-netcom.org` is not visible in internet... so it must be a computer inside your local network

Comment: Thanks @UXDart . That was it. I should have realized that